# How to preserve the number of errors at the level of the package in SQL or .txt file?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014

This is my package.

[image: SSIS package]

Does anyone know how to preserve the number of errors at the level of the package in SQL or .txt file? I'm new in SSIS. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Event Handlers tab then select *OnError* from the dropdown. Here you can send an email on any error or you can develop your own custom logic to log errors into a DB or write them to a text file.

Also, you can choose from existing logging mechanisms available in SSIS. Click on the menu item "SSIS", you will see the first option as Logging then you will see different options to log errors/warnings.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Store the number in a package-level variable.